# Export page to html

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, export

I want to export whole page as an html page. In other words, i will be selecting an element on page and whole html inside that element should be saved into html file.

So far,i've tried this

```
$("#Export").click(function () {        
        window.location.href = "ExportToHTML?html=" + $(".innerpage-wrap").html();
    });
```

*ExportToHTML* is the action of controller. This gives me only first two lines of the page. Don't know what the problem is. It's truncating all html after '#'.

Any views on this? Alternative way to do the same will also be fine.

Comment: Browsers do not send anything in a query string after a `#` (fragment identifier). You could do a POST instead.

Comment: My guess would be u need to escape the HTML string before passing as value, which is why its currently failing. Also sending it as a POST request would make more sense since GET does have a small size limit in terms of data transfer.

Answer (score 2):

> It's truncating all html after '#'.

This is because the `#` has a special meaning in a URL - it's the fragment. To fix the issue you need to URL encode the HTML you're sending in the querystring:

```
$("#Export").click(function () {        
  window.location.assign('ExportToHTML?html=' + encodeURIComponent($(".innerpage-wrap").html()));
});
```